# MagicalRecord findByAttribute returning inverse relationship documents issue

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm having an issue figuring out how to model/fetch items with Core Data and MagicalRecord. I have two entities, **`User`** and **`Message`**, which both have inverse relationships to each other:

**User Entity**

```
Relationship    Destination    Inverse    Type
-------------------------------------------------
messages        Message        user       To Many
```

**Message Entity**

```
Relationship    Destination    Inverse    Type
-------------------------------------------------
user            User           messages   To One
```

**Issue**

When fetching messages by a given user, MagicalRecord is returning 2x the number of records since it's matching attributes at the `user` and `user.messages.user` keyPaths:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchMessagesByUser:(NSString *)identifier {

    // returning 2x the records it should
    return [Message MR_findByAttribute:@"user.identifier" withValue:identifier];
}
```

Should I change the way I'm using MagicalRecord or is there a fundamental issue with my Core Data model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I setup an app with MagicalRecord using a `to many` relationship, and then run the app a few times, the User gets saved again and again, so I see double(and triple) the number of Messages because the same User has been saved several times.

If you try changing the attribute values for the User in your code--so that a User with unique attributes is created the next time you run your program--I think you'll see that the number of Messages will be what you expect.

You can see all the Users by adding this code:

```
NSArray* users = [User MR_findAll];

for(User* user in users) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [user name]);  //Log whatever attributes you want
}
```

If I'm right, that will reveal that you have multiple Users with identical attributes.

========

Because there is so little information on MagicalRecord, I'm going to post what I did to setup the app.  I used Xcode 6.3.2.

1)  I created an OSX Cocoa application which I named `MagicalRecord2`.  I did `NOT` check Use Core Data.

2) In a Terminal window, I executed the command:

```
~$ gem install cocoapods  //However, you probably need to use sudo(see below)
```

On my system, I have multiple versions of ruby installed (using rvm to manage them), and you should never use `sudo` with rvm, but if you only have the system install of ruby, then you will need to use `sudo` to install the gem: `$ sudo gem install cocoapods`

3) In Terminal, I changed directories(cd) into my project directory:

```
~$ cd ~/xcode_projects/MagicalRecord2/
```

4)  In the project directory, I created a file named `Podfile` with this
content:

```
pod "MagicalRecord"
```

Then I saved the file.

5) Then I ran the command

```
~/xcode_projects/MagicalRecord2$ pod update
```

When that command finished, it printed out the message:

> [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use
>   `MagicalRecord2.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

So I quit Xcode, and I used Finder to navigate to my project directory,  and I clicked on `MagicalRecord2.xcworkspace` to open Xcode.  If you expand a few of the groups in the Project Navigator, you’ll soon see the normal AppDelegate.h/.m files, etc.

6)  In AppDelegate (or you can do it an NSWindowController subclass that you create), I added the following import:

```
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>
```

7) Then I created the models:  `File>New>OSX:CoreData>Data Model`

I named the file `MyModels.xcdatamodeld` and accepted the defaults.  Then in the Project Navigator, I clicked on the `MyModels.xcdatamodeld` file, which opened up the Entity Editor.   At the bottom of the Entity Editor, I clicked on Add Entity.  Then I double clicked on “Entity” and changed "Entity" to “User”. Under Attributes, I clicked on the `+`, and I added a `name` attribute of type String.  In similar fashion, I added a Message entity with a ‘text’ attribute of type String.

[image]

Then I clicked on the `User` entity again, and in the`Relationships` section I clicked on the `+`, and under the *Relationship* column I typed in `messages`(lower case, plural), and for *Destination* I chose `Message`.  Next, on the far right hand side of the Xcode window, at the top there is a group of three icons, I selected the third icon--the `Data Model Inspector`.  With the `messages` relationship highlighted, if you look in the Data Model Inspector you will see a heading that says *Relationship* and in that section you can see `Type` with a value of `To One`.  Change the `Type` to `To Many`:

[image]

Next, way over on the left side of the Entity Editor, click on the `Message` entity, and in the *Relationships* section click the ‘+’, and name the relationship ‘user’(singular, lower case), and for *Inverse* select `messages`.

[image]

If you go back to the `User` entity, you will see that under *Relationships>Inverse* it now says `user`.

There are other settings in the Data Model Inspector that are worth setting, but you’ll have to read up on those.  For this demo, nothing else is needed.

8) With `MyModels.xcdatamodeld` still highlighted in the Project Navigator, look up at the top of your screen, and in the Xcode Menu bar select `Editor>Create NSManagedObject Subclass`.  In the popup window, I checked `MyModels`, then I clicked on Next, then I checked both `User` and `Message`, then I clicked on Next again.  This next screen really screwed me up: Xcode asks you where you want to save the new files that are going to be created.  By default Xcode adds the files outside your project directory, but they appear in the Project Navigator, so they look like they are in the project.  But later, when I tried to import those files I got an error saying the files couldn’t be found.  My response was, “What the ~!@#~!@#!@ do you mean??!  The files are right there in the Project Navigator!!”

So, make sure you carefully choose to add the files to a group (i.e. a folder) that is inside your project, e.g. the MagicalRecord2 group(folder) for me.  It’s a little confusing because there are two or three things named “YourProjectName”, and you have to navigate to the group(folder) named “YourProjectName” when you choose where to save the new files.  DO NOT ACCEPT THE DEFAULT LOCATION.

If you do things correctly, you will see the new files User.h/.m and Message.h/.m inside the “YourProjectName” group(folder).  Here's what it will look like if you do it INCORRECTLY:

[image]

See how the files at the top are not inside the MagicalRecord2 group(folder)?

9) Now setup MagicalRecord:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  MagicalRecord2
//


#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application

    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
}

@end
```

As you can see, you only need two lines to setup Magical Record, which in turn will take care of setting up Core Data for you.

10) Next, write a convenience method that you can call to create and save a new User:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>
#import "User.h"
#import "Message.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
...
...

- (void)persistNewUserWithName:(NSString*) name {

    NSManagedObjectContext* defaultContext =
    [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]; //[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] => deprecated

    User* myUser = [User MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext]; //Requires that you import User.h.
    [myUser setName: name];

    Message* msg1 = [Message MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext];  //Requires that you import Message.h
    [msg1 setText:@"Hello"];
    [msg1 setUser:myUser];

    Message* msg2 = [Message MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext];
    [msg2 setText:@"Goodbye"];
    [msg2 setUser:myUser];

    //I commented out the following line so that the database starts out  
    //empty every time I run the project:

    //[defaultContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];  //[defaultContext MR_save] => deprecated

}

@end
```

11) Use MagicalRecord to query Core Data:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];


    [self persistNewUserWithName:@"Rokkor"];
    NSArray* users = [User MR_findAll];
    NSLog(@"User count: %lu", (unsigned long)[users count]);

    for(User* user in users) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [user name]);
    }

    NSArray* matchingMessages =
    [Message MR_findByAttribute:@"user.name" withValue:@"Rokkor"];
    //When you search in the Message entity, as above, you can write "user.name", 
    //but if you search in the User entity, you cannot write "messages"

    for (Message* msg in matchingMessages) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [msg text]);
    }



}
```

I got an error saying the file `NSManagedObject.h` couldn’t be found.  In User.m, there was the line:

```
#import NSManagedObject.h
```

I commented out that line, and things seemed to work.  Xcode created that file, and I’m not sure why it created a file with an import statement for a file that doesn’t exist.

Here's the console output:

```
2015-06-28 19:42:24.845 MagicalRecord2[2924:73871] Created new private queue context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6000001e7100>
2015-06-28 19:42:24.845 MagicalRecord2[2924:73871] Set root saving context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6000001e7100>
2015-06-28 19:42:24.845 MagicalRecord2[2924:73871] Created new main queue context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6080001e4900>
2015-06-28 19:42:24.846 MagicalRecord2[2924:73871] Set default context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6080001e4900>
2015-06-28 19:42:24.847 MagicalRecord2[2924:73871] User count: 1
2015-06-28 19:42:24.847 MagicalRecord2[2924:73871] Rokkor
2015-06-28 19:42:24.848 MagicalRecord2[2924:73871] Hello
2015-06-28 19:42:24.848 MagicalRecord2[2924:73871] Goodbye
```

Here are a couple of other options:

1)  You can use a block to get the defaultContext and save the data:

```
 [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext* defaultContext) {

     User* myUser = [User MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext];
     [myUser setName: name];


     Message* m1 = [Message MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext];
     [m1 setText:@"Hello"];
     [m1 setUser:myUser];

     Message* m2 = [Message MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext];
     [m2 setText:@"Goodbye"];
     [m2 setUser:myUser];

 }];
```

Presumably, saveWithBlock() is defined something like this:

```
(void)saveWithBlock:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext*))yourBlock {

    NSManagedObjectContext* context =
        [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]; 

    yourBlock(context)

    [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}
```

As a result, saveWithBlock() automatically saves whatever you add to the context.

2) You can use a filter when querying the data:

```
NSPredicate* messagesFilter =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.name == %@ && text == %@",
 @"Rokkor", @"Hello"];

NSArray* matchingMessages = [Message MR_findAllWithPredicate:messagesFilter];

for (Message* msg in matchingMessages) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [msg text]);
}
```

Comment: This is an extremely thorough answer.  I'm sure several that stumble upon it will find it useful. Thank you.